# How to get Multiple Range and setvalue the Multiple Range to another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

i want from the range shUserForm Get Range B14:O100 what ever record in it will send all the the data to another spreadsheet. i already achived is that when i click or run the script.i only getting 1 data from B14:014 instead i want each Column read it as a getRange.

```
// @ts-nocheck function sendItem() {

  var myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   var shUserForm=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("InputForm");


  //TO Create the Instance of the User-Inteface Enviroment tp use Alert features

  /*var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var response=ui.alert("Submit", "Do you want to Submit the Record?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  if(response==ui.Button.NO) {

  return;//Exit the submit response

  }
*/

/////////////////////////////////// - Connection to another Spreadsheet   SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();   var myDataBarong = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1zwH6fMLG3N5eknt9lXqVwj8BJHTX-i9jTmXn_gZotTw'); var dataSheet= myDataBarong.getSheetByName("DATA"); //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var blankRow2=dataSheet.getLastRow()+1;

  //Code to Update the Item Product   dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B14:B100").getValue());
```

dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C14:C100").getValue()); dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D14:D100").getValue());
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E14:E100").getValue());
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F14:F100").getValue());
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("G14:G100").getValue());
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 7).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D10").getValue());
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 8).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd-mm-YYYY h:mm am/pm');
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 9).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()); //Get User

```
// Clear Content From Form

/*shUserForm.getRange("B14:B100").clearContent();*/


/*ui.alert('DATA HAS BEEN RECORDED!')*/

}
```

Comment: In my Main Spreadsheet 
when i click CONFIRM AND RESET Button
[link]https://ibb.co/0GfGkRw

then it all fill the data from the B4:O100  will send the data to setvalue to another spreadsheet which is this picture https://ibb.co/dmnRrGP

Comment: in my currently code im only getting B4 value only the whole row instead i want all the data .

Comment: Instead of screenshot, please provide [minimal reproducible sample sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can better help you.

Comment: https://anotepad.com/notes/g2m4hxca - here

Comment: im new here i dont know how to share the whole sample sheets

Comment: You are using `setValue/getValue` which will only get one value. Try `setValues/getValues`.  And you could `getValues(“C14:G100”)`

Comment: @TheWizEd im getting error with the setvalues and getvalues

Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my understanding of your script and explanation.
The problem with your script is at:

```
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2,2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C14:C100").getValue());
```

Explanation from your last comment:

The error that you've got if you change to getValues() and setValues() is because of the condition of the setValues() method. You have to declare the number of rows and columns you want to print at the setValues() parameter. You can look at the documentation of setValues().

This is my suggestion for your problem:

```
var data = shUserForm.getRange("C14:C100").getValues();
dataSheet.getRange(blankRow2, 2, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

Comment: thanks it works. last question. how about for example Single Value From B1 then it will copy it and paste it depends on the range of other set values..

Comment: For this case, you can use the getValue() method, but you don't need to insert the length of rows and columns in the getRange(). **Single value from B1** then it will using getRange(1, 2). @JovenNicolas